# Float sum with javascript

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I'm calculating the sum of several float values using javascript and... I've noticed a strange thing never seen before. Executing this code:

```
parseFloat('2.3') + parseFloat('2.4')
```

I obtain **4.699999999999999**

So... what sould I do to obtain a correct value? (supposed that this is incorrect...)

Comment: I am not saying this will help with this question. But I always like to point out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182416/A-Collection-of-JavaScript-Gotchas) in times like this

Comment: While searching for this, I do not see how this question is duplicate - the problem is not solved on the question marked as duplicate, and still, in the whole SO, I have not found a proper solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Once you read what [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) you could use the [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function:

```
var result = parseFloat('2.3') + parseFloat('2.4');
alert(result.toFixed(2));​
```

Comment: Simply use `parseFloat((2.3 + 2.4).toFixed(10))` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51723472/4344976) is the explanation

Comment: Pay attention that `toFixed(fractionDigits)` returns a string

Comment: this is not a real solutions whereas my numbers are different 1+1.2+1.25+4.5=???

Comment: @Monzur—you can do *toFixed* on the result: `Number((1+1.2+1.25+4.5).toFixed(10))` will return a number. If you need more than 10 decimal places you might need to use [*BigInt*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) instead.

Answer (score 13):

```
(parseFloat('2.3') + parseFloat('2.4')).toFixed(1);
```

its going to give you solution i suppose